# Behavior of Future map and foreach

Tags: scala

I have following code that prints the current thread name in map and future

```
object ConcurrencyTest1 {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
    import scala.concurrent.Future
    println("main thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName)


    Future {
      println("future job: " + Thread.currentThread().getName)
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      10
    }.map { x => {
      println("map: " + Thread.currentThread().getName)
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      x * x
    }
    }.foreach { x => {
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      println("foreach: " + Thread.currentThread().getName)
      println(x)
    }
    }

    Thread.sleep(5000)
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
main thread: main
future job: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5
map: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5
foreach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5
```

From the output, the future job, map and foreach are all run in the same thread.
I want to ask whether this result is deterministic， that is， it will always output the same result. Or, they may be run in different thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is guaranteed...

However, in you case I think this follows from the `Thread.sleep` calls (when they are completed, the next Future that's waiting to be processed is either the subsequent map/foreach; other Futures were already started on other available threads).

You can see this by removing the `Thread.sleep` calls:

*Note: To get more data this iterates over many args.*

```
object ConcurrencyTestNoSleep {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
    import scala.concurrent.Future
    println("main thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName)

    args.map { a =>
      Future {
        println(s"future job $a: " + Thread.currentThread().getName)
        // Thread.sleep(1)
        10
      }.map { x => {
        println(s"map $a: " + Thread.currentThread().getName)
        // Thread.sleep(1)
        x * x
      }
      }.foreach { x => {
        // Thread.sleep(1)
        println(s"foreach $a:" + Thread.currentThread().getName)
        // println(x)
      }
    }
  }
  Thread.sleep(5000)
  }
}
```

When run:

```
@ ConcurrencyTestNoSleep.main(Array[String]("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g") )
main thread: main
future job a: scala-execution-context-global-954
map a: scala-execution-context-global-954
foreach a:scala-execution-context-global-955
future job c: scala-execution-context-global-955
map c: scala-execution-context-global-955
foreach c:scala-execution-context-global-955
future job d: scala-execution-context-global-955
map d: scala-execution-context-global-955
foreach d:scala-execution-context-global-955
future job e: scala-execution-context-global-955
map e: scala-execution-context-global-955
foreach e:scala-execution-context-global-955
future job f: scala-execution-context-global-955
map f: scala-execution-context-global-955
foreach f:scala-execution-context-global-955
future job g: scala-execution-context-global-955
map g: scala-execution-context-global-955
foreach g:scala-execution-context-global-955
future job b: scala-execution-context-global-954
map b: scala-execution-context-global-954
foreach b:scala-execution-context-global-954
```

You can see in the third line, that `"a"` has run across two different threads this time.

---

However, with the sleep it does seem reuse the same threads:

```
object ConcurrencyTestSleep {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
    import scala.concurrent.Future
    println("main thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName)

    args.map { a =>
      Future {
        println(s"future job $a: " + Thread.currentThread().getName)
        Thread.sleep(1)
        10
      }.map { x => {
        println(s"map $a: " + Thread.currentThread().getName)
        Thread.sleep(1)
        x * x
      }
      }.foreach { x => {
        Thread.sleep(1)
        println(s"foreach $a:" + Thread.currentThread().getName)
        // println(x)
      }
    }
  }
  Thread.sleep(5000)
  }
}
```

Here each arg uses the same thread (in the map and the foreach):

```
@ ConcurrencyTestSleep.main(Array[String]("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g") )
main thread: main
future job a: scala-execution-context-global-1162
map a: scala-execution-context-global-1162
future job c: scala-execution-context-global-1164
future job b: scala-execution-context-global-1163
future job d: scala-execution-context-global-1165
map b: scala-execution-context-global-1163
map c: scala-execution-context-global-1164
map d: scala-execution-context-global-1165
foreach a:scala-execution-context-global-1162
future job e: scala-execution-context-global-1162
foreach b:scala-execution-context-global-1163
foreach d:scala-execution-context-global-1165
future job g: scala-execution-context-global-1165
foreach c:scala-execution-context-global-1164
map e: scala-execution-context-global-1162
future job f: scala-execution-context-global-1163
map g: scala-execution-context-global-1165
map f: scala-execution-context-global-1163
foreach e:scala-execution-context-global-1162
foreach f:scala-execution-context-global-1162
foreach g:scala-execution-context-global-1165
```

That said, I would not rely on this!

Comment: My suspicion being that the main reason is that Thread.sleep is not precise in its timing, that's why the next Future is the only one available at completion of the previous step.

Comment: Thanks @andy. I loop my code in the question for 200 times, and I could see the result that it is not ganranteed to be in the same thread